# Extract some basic data with beautiful soup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

Recently I tried to start web-scraping with python, in order to extract some basic informations in instagram using beautiful soup.

I wrote a simple code which is showed below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = 'http://instagram.com/umnpics/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for x in soup.findAll('li', {'class':'photo'}):
    print (x)
```

but after run it, some exceptions occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mhdn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mhdn\Desktop\test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Mhdn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Mhdn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: try adding the path here: `driver = webdriver.Firefox('path/to/geckodriver')`

Comment: did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to download `geckodriver` to your local system from [**here**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- In your code you need to provide **executable_path** for the **`geckodriver`**

Adding `executable_path` to your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = 'http://instagram.com/umnpics/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= 'path/to/geckodriver')   #<---Add path to your geckodriver

#example: driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= 'home/downloads/geckodriver')

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for x in soup.findAll('li', {'class':'photo'}):
    print (x)
```